# Ansible replace xml element value on lines with a specific attribute

Tags: linux, xml, ansible

I have the below content from xml in which I am trying to parameterize value="" for lines with name="database".

for example the current value which is value="test.abc.com" in line 1 should be replaced with a different value as value="new_test.abc.com".

Note: There are multiple such lines in the xml file, the one below is just a part of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:resources.j2c="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/resources.j2c.xmi">
<resources.jdbc:JDBCProvider xmi:id="JDBCProvider_1" name="Oracle JDBC Driver (XA)" description="JDBC provider" providerType="Oracle JDBC Driver (XA)" isolatedClassloader="false" implementationClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" xa="false">
    <classpath>${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/jdbc/Lib/gidbc7.jar</classpath>
    <classpath>$(ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/jdbc/Lib/oidbc:.jar</classpath>
    <classpath>${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/rdbms/1L1b/xdb6.jar</classpath>
    <factories xmi:type="resources. jdbc: DataSource" xmi:id="DataSource_1" name="DWLConfig" JndiName="jdbc/DWLConfig" description="XA Datasource for">
    <propertySet xmi:id="J2EEResourcePropertySet_1">
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1" name="databaseName" type="java.lang.String" value="test.abc.com" required="true"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_2" name="driverType" type="java.Lang.String" value="4" description="" required="true"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_3" name="serverName" type="java.lang.String" value="test-scan.abc.com" required="true"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_4" name="portNumber" type="java.lang.String" value="1521" description="" required="true"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_5" name="webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel" type="java.lang.Integer" value="2"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_6" name= "downgradeHoldCursorsUnderXa" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_7" name="UseRRASetEquals" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true" description="Set for pME"/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_8" name="currentSchema" type="java.lang.String" value="INITIATE" description=""/>
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_9" name="URL" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </propertySet>
    <connectionPool xmi:id="ConnectionPool_1" connectionTimeout="180" maxConnections="85" minConnections="I" reapTime="180" unusedTimeout="1800"/>
    <mapping xmi:id="MappingModule_1" mappingConfigAlias="" authDataAlias="Node01/User-config"/>
    </factories>
</resources.jdbc:JDBCProvider>
</xmi:XMI>
```

I have tried using:

```
- name: xml update
  xml:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    xpath: /xmi:XMI/resources.jdbc:JDBCProvider/factories/propertySet/resourceProperties[@name="database"]
    attribute: value
    value: new_test.abc.com
    state: present
  with_items:
    - file1.xml
    - file2.xml
```

But it throws the following error:

```
XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Undefined namespace prefix" means you're using a namespace prefix in your XML, but you haven't told Ansible what XML namespace that corresponds to. If you see an element name like `<xmi:XMI>`, that leading `xmi:` prefix is just a pointer to the actual namespace, which in this document is `http://www.omg.org/XMI`.

So in your `xml` task, you need to provide the [`namespaces`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html#parameter-namespaces) key to map prefixes to actual namespaces:

```
- name: xml update
  xml:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    xpath: /xmi:XMI/resources.jdbc:JDBCProvider/factories/propertySet/resourceProperties[@name="database"]
    attribute: value
    value: new_test.abc.com
    state: present
    namespaces:
      xmi: http://www.omg.org/XMI
      resources.jdbc: ...something...
  with_items:
    - file1.xml
    - file2.xml
```

The XML you've posted is invalid; it uses the `resources.jdbc` namespace prefix but doesn't actually define it anywhere. You'll need to fix that (and add the appropriate entry to the `namespaces` dictionary in your task) in order for your playbook to work.

Comment: I'd guess it's a typo from the defined `resources.j2c`

Comment: Related to that, watch out, the one in question is actually `databaseName`, thus:  `[@name="databaseName"]`